# How to fix "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed"

Tags: ssl, https

I updated my application from market store,then I tried to login with my account,but it failed and shows the error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed.

But when I killed the app in task manager or reboot my phone, it worked fine and did't appear the error anymore.How can I fix this.

I have searched some answers, some answers show my certificate expired, but why does it work fine when I reboot the phone and restart my app.

```
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:355)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.c.b.a(RealConnection.java:195)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.c.b.a(RealConnection.java:148)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.c.b.a(RealConnection.java:111)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.b.r.a(StreamAllocation.java:188)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.b.r.b(StreamAllocation.java:127)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.b.r.a(StreamAllocation.java:97)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.b.g.o(HttpEngine.java:289)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.a.b.g.a(HttpEngine.java:241)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.z.a(RealCall.java:240)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.z$a.a(RealCall.java:198)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.z.a(RealCall.java:160)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at okhttp3.z.b(RealCall.java:57)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.yaok.a.g.a(HttpLoader.java:190)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.yaok.a.d.a(DataLoader.java:308)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.yaok.a.d.a(DataLoader.java:72)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.yaok.a.j.run(Loader.java:10)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:705)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:537)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:558)
04-25 10:35:30.505  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:603)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:493)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:416)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:337)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:203)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:592)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:351)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    ... 16 more
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:133)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:225)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:143)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:301)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:701)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    ... 28 more
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: Certificate expired at Tue Jan 15 15:39:44 GMT+08:00 2019 (compared to Thu Apr 25 10:35:30 GMT+08:00 2019)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.checkValidity(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:244)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(BasicChecker.java:194)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:144)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
04-25 10:35:30.506  9127 15685 W System.err:    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Have you get this error from where? Web or Mobile App. If mobile means which platform and OS version.

Comment: Sorry,It's so long time.It's on Android 8.1 platform and I had resolved it. First I think we only have one server site, but in fatc, We have two server site :(.Our maintenance engineer only updated one site's certificate,So when I visited the other site by some operation, the error occured. When he updated the other site's certificate, It solved.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for your response. Me too face same platform with Android 9.0. I too solve this one how?, I added network security config file with my project. It resolved now.